# Using Pandas how to use column data for statistics analysis for big data

Tags: python, pandas

In my data set, I have 48000 Villages and each village have 10 to 12 crops, and crop area of sown for each crop in each villages, I want to find out for which crop have major area in which villages, And out of all crops what is the percentage for crop 1 to ... crop n in that villages. i.e I want to find out the proportion of crops village wise,if village A has  crop-1 & crop-2, then what percentage of A have for crop-1&crop-2

So,next I can rank the villages for the particular crop.so after that I can understand which crop is big area sown for which villages.

```
  District   Taluka            Village Name       Crop        Area in hec
0   Ahmednagar  Pathardi          Alhanwadi   Bajara        370.0
1   Ahmednagar  Pathardi             Adgaon   Bajara        302.0
2   Ahmednagar  Pathardi       Ambika Nagar   Bajara         40.0
3   Ahmednagar  Pathardi         Bharajwadi   Bajara         90.0
4   Ahmednagar  Pathardi           Bhalgaon   Bajara        254.0
5   Ahmednagar  Pathardi  Bhawarwadi (N.V.)   Bajara         35.0
6   Ahmednagar  Pathardi           Badewadi   Bajara         17.0
7   Ahmednagar  Pathardi              Akola   Bajara        175.0
8   Ahmednagar  Pathardi          Auranjpur   Bajara         35.0
9   Ahmednagar  Pathardi          Agaskhand   Bajara        100.0
10  Ahmednagar  Pathardi          Alhanwadi   Cotton        150.0
11  Ahmednagar  Pathardi             Adgaon   Cotton        310.0
12  Ahmednagar  Pathardi       Ambika Nagar   Cotton        131.0
13  Ahmednagar  Pathardi         Bharajwadi   Cotton        161.0
14  Ahmednagar  Pathardi           Bhalgaon   Cotton        562.0
15  Ahmednagar  Pathardi  Bhawarwadi (N.V.)   Cotton        211.0
16  Ahmednagar  Pathardi           Badewadi   Cotton        104.0
17  Ahmednagar  Pathardi              Akola   Cotton        550.0
18  Ahmednagar  Pathardi          Auranjpur   Cotton          0.0
19  Ahmednagar  Pathardi          Agaskhand   Cotton          0.0
20  Ahmednagar  Pathardi          Alhanwadi  Soybean         26.0
21  Ahmednagar  Pathardi             Adgaon  Soybean         52.0
22  Ahmednagar  Pathardi       Ambika Nagar  Soybean         72.0
23  Ahmednagar  Pathardi         Bharajwadi  Soybean         88.0
24  Ahmednagar  Pathardi           Bhalgaon  Soybean         90.0
25  Ahmednagar  Pathardi  Bhawarwadi (N.V.)  Soybean         93.0
26  Ahmednagar  Pathardi           Badewadi  Soybean        100.0
27  Ahmednagar  Pathardi              Akola  Soybean         10.0
28  Ahmednagar  Pathardi          Auranjpur  Soybean         45.0
29  Ahmednagar  Pathardi          Agaskhand  Soybean         20.0
30  Ahmednagar  Pathardi          Alhanwadi    Maize         10.0
31  Ahmednagar  Pathardi             Adgaon    Maize          1.5
32  Ahmednagar  Pathardi       Ambika Nagar    Maize          3.0
33  Ahmednagar  Pathardi         Bharajwadi    Maize          5.0
34  Ahmednagar  Pathardi           Bhalgaon    Maize         12.0
35  Ahmednagar  Pathardi  Bhawarwadi (N.V.)    Maize         51.0
36  Ahmednagar  Pathardi           Badewadi    Maize          5.0
37  Ahmednagar  Pathardi              Akola    Maize         25.0
38  Ahmednagar  Pathardi          Auranjpur    Maize          5.0
39  Ahmednagar  Pathardi          Agaskhand    Maize         10.0
```

---

```
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

D=pd.read_excel("/media/desktop/Sample-2.xlsx","Sheet1")

village=D["Village Name"].unique()

crop=D["Crop"].unique()

q1=[]

for i in village:

    for j in crop:
        a=D["Village Name"]==i
        b=D["Crop"]==j
        D1=D[a&b]
        q1.append(D1)
q2=[]

for i in q1:

    if i.empty==False:
        q2.append(i)
```

Now we can get village wise crops sown area in hectare, next we have to calculate village A  % for crop-1 , % for crop-2 ... % crop-n.

Formula : For Village A for Crop-1 is Crop-1/All crops in that village, and we get Crop-1 % for that village, same way find out % for Crop-2.

Same for all villages.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First for top crop per village use:

```
df1 = df.sort_values(['Village Name','Area in hec'], ascending=[True, False])

df2 = df1.drop_duplicates('Village Name')
print (df2)
      District    Taluka       Village Name     Crop  Area in hec
11  Ahmednagar  Pathardi             Adgaon   Cotton        310.0
9   Ahmednagar  Pathardi          Agaskhand   Bajara        100.0
17  Ahmednagar  Pathardi              Akola   Cotton        550.0
0   Ahmednagar  Pathardi          Alhanwadi   Bajara        370.0
12  Ahmednagar  Pathardi       Ambika Nagar   Cotton        131.0
28  Ahmednagar  Pathardi          Auranjpur  Soybean         45.0
16  Ahmednagar  Pathardi           Badewadi   Cotton        104.0
14  Ahmednagar  Pathardi           Bhalgaon   Cotton        562.0
13  Ahmednagar  Pathardi         Bharajwadi   Cotton        161.0
15  Ahmednagar  Pathardi  Bhawarwadi (N.V.)   Cotton        211.0
```

And percentage of area per crop:

```
s = df1.groupby("Crop")['Area in hec'].transform('sum')
df1['perc'] =  df1['Area in hec'].div(s).mul(100)
print (df1.head(10))
      District    Taluka Village Name     Crop  Area in hec       perc
11  Ahmednagar  Pathardi       Adgaon   Cotton        310.0  14.226709
1   Ahmednagar  Pathardi       Adgaon   Bajara        302.0  21.297602
21  Ahmednagar  Pathardi       Adgaon  Soybean         52.0   8.724832
31  Ahmednagar  Pathardi       Adgaon    Maize          1.5   1.176471
9   Ahmednagar  Pathardi    Agaskhand   Bajara        100.0   7.052186
29  Ahmednagar  Pathardi    Agaskhand  Soybean         20.0   3.355705
39  Ahmednagar  Pathardi    Agaskhand    Maize         10.0   7.843137
19  Ahmednagar  Pathardi    Agaskhand   Cotton          0.0   0.000000
17  Ahmednagar  Pathardi        Akola   Cotton        550.0  25.240936
7   Ahmednagar  Pathardi        Akola   Bajara        175.0  12.341326
```

Comment: your logic was correct. you give me the villages which is top per that crop. but, I can't ignore the other crops in that villages, so I need each crops percentage for same villages. next we can see, for crop : Cotton, 48000 villages in descending order. etc... so,  need all villages for all crops

Comment: thank you, in the last, how to crop wise we can get descending order for percentage column?

Comment: @Kiran - answer was edited, for avoid 2 times sorting was output of sorting assign to `df1` and reuse from first solution to second.

Comment: sir, how can we do percentage column descending order as a crop wise? so, we can get for crop cotton- village-1 is highest percentage, village-2 is second highest percentage....so on? same way for crop-Soybean  village-1 is highest percentage, village-2 is second highest percentage

Comment: @Kiran - Do you think `df3 = df.sort_values(['Crop','Area in hec'], ascending=[True, False])
s = df3.groupby("Crop")['Area in hec'].transform('sum')
df3['perc'] =  df3['Area in hec'].div(s).mul(100)` ?

Comment: sir, can you please help me out for my new question uploaded, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58481693/after-using-groupby-or-pivot-count-function-in-pandas-how-to-apply-some-analysis

Answer (score 0):

first use groupby to aggregate the sum of area for each City into a total

```
total_lands = D.groupby(["Village Name"])['Area in hec'].agg(['sum']).drop_index()
```

Then groupby city and crop to get the total for each crop in each city

```
lands_by_crop = D.groupby(["Village Name","Crop"])['Area in hec'].agg(['sum'])
```

finally calculate the percentages ...

```
percentages = lands_by_crop.map(lambda x:x/total_lands[x.index["Village Name"]])
```

I think should work (not entirely sure on that last step) ... and there *may* be a more efficient way to solve it, im not sure

Comment: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'drop_index' give me error

Answer (score 0):

To find out the quantity of crops-village wise, use the following:

```
D.filter(items = ["VillageName","Crop", "Area"],axis=1).groupby(by = ["VillageName","Crop"])
```

You can then divide by sumTotal of crops Area(D.filter(items = ["Crop", "Area"],axis=1).groupby(by = "Crop")) or sumTotal of Village Area (D.filter(items = ["VillageName", "Area"],axis=1).groupby(by = "VillageName"))to get the proportions.